# zoom in SVG with place clicked remaining in the same place

Tags: javascript, html, svg, zooming, translate

For quite a while I have been dealing with this scenario where I want to zoom in on an SVG image by clicking on it (or tapping in case of a touch-screen device), having it so that where you have clicked stays in the same position on the page while zooming in.

What happens at the moment is that when zooming is done, the pivot is not the clicked point but another point. It seems I cannot get to think of the correct formula to translate the svg as zooming in is done. Preferably I would see a solution that doesn't use an external library as the code below is a simplified version of a bigger project that has quite complicated stuff that would propably not be as easy to refactor to another component.

```js
let zoomedIn = false;
let svgViewboxWidth, svgViewboxHeight;
let factor = 1;

function init() {
    svgViewboxWidth = 335.2262416700105;
    svgViewboxHeight = 304.65863467997406;

    let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svgContainer');
    svgContainer.addEventListener('click', svgClick);
}

function svgClick(event) {
    let newCalcX = 28, newCalcY = -86;
    let gZoom = document.getElementById('zoomscale');
    if (zoomedIn) {
        // zoom out
        factor = 1;
        newCalcX = 0;
        newCalcY = 0;
        zoomedIn = false;
    } else {
        // zoom in
        factor = 3;
        newCalcX = (event.clientX - 86) * -1;
        newCalcY = (event.clientY + 28) * -1;
        zoomedIn = true;
    }
    let transformValue = `translate(${newCalcX}, ${newCalcY}) scale(${factor})`;
    gZoom.setAttribute('transform', transformValue);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG zoom issue</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="svgContainer" class="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="view" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 335.2262416700105 304.65863467997406" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" class="view">
          <style>svg { background-color:rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1); }</style>
          <g id="zoomscale">
            <line x1="20" x2="310" y1="150" y2="150" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px" />
            <line x1="165" x2="165" y1="20" y2="280" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px" />
            <circle cx="165" cy="150" r="20" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none" />
            <circle cx="165" cy="150" r="40" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none" />
            <circle cx="165" cy="150" r="60" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none" />
            <circle cx="165" cy="150" r="90" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none" />
            <circle cx="165" cy="150" r="120" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none" />
          </g>
        </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious, or maybe I am just not able to calculate the correct translate- values for zooming. Massive thanks to the one(s) who can help me with this!

Comment: See: [https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/)

Comment: Looks like a very helpful article. Gonna try this out!